# SQL Search for words from one sentence in another sentence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server, I have two strings. Need to check if string1 has any matching words in string2. It should exactly match at least a word in the sentence.

String2: Hello String How Are You

Match Scenario: String1: Hello How Am I String1

Hello is common in both strings

No match Scenario: String1: Am I String1

No Word is common in the strings

Comment: You'll have to use [Full-Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16) indexes and functions to do this easily with good performance. Normal indexes are only good for exact or range matches. Looking for a word inside a field can't use normal indexes and requires scanning the entire table, splitting values and checking them *every* time.

Comment: It sounds like you shouldn't be storing these groups of words as sentences at all, maybe you should be storing each word on its own row. Then a join becomes trivial. Also your "no match" scenario seems like a bad example - don't both sentences contain `How`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to your last question, we just join the results of string_split()

```
declare @string2 varchar(max) = 'Hello String How Are You';
declare @string1 varchar(max) = 'Hello How Am I String1';

Select A.Value
 From string_split(@string2,' ') A
 Join string_split(@string1,' ') B
   on A.value=B.value
 Group By A.value
```

**Results**

```
Value
Hello
How
```

Comment: This works in very simple scenarios, but quickly falls down when punctuation is added e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/TbQ02HBs There are probably very convoluted methods you could use to do this without using full text search, but you'd be re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @GarethD Agreed.  We mentioned punctuation in OP's prior question.